# Magento 2 Get selected Country Code and Subtotal in Shipping Method

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Just wondering if it is possible to get customer shipping country id and Cart Subtotal price in my custom shipping module so that i can change api hit as per customer selected country and Cart subtotal. Please Check my code.

```
$url = "https://api.areatrend.com/fulfillment/shipping-rate.php?cc=US&t=0.00";
    //  Initiate curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $resp[] = json_decode($result, true);
    $countresp = count($resp[0][0]);
    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
    for($i =0; $i < $countresp; $i++)
    {
        //echo $resp[0][$i]['method']. "<br>";
        $shippmethod = $resp[0][$i]['method'];
        $price = $resp[0][$i]['price'];
        $edd = $resp[0][$i]['edd'];
        /*store shipping in session*/
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($edd);
        /* Use method name */
        $method->setMethod($this->_code.$i);
        $method->setMethodTitle($shippmethod);
        $method->setCost($price);
        $method->setPrice($price);
        $result->append($method);
    }
```

Check there is CC which is country code and p which is price in api url. I want to change it as per customer selected country and cart subtotal price. Hope anyone can help. I am working on Magento 2.